# C# Web Request Attachment file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm need to create an HTTP POST and to send a file with a request.
I'm using in c#.

I was able to create such a request. The problem is that the sent file is invalid.

```
if (files != null)
{
    foreach (string key in files.Keys)
    {
        if (File.Exists(files[key]))
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            formItemBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=test.msg  \r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary \r\nContent-ID: <test.msg> \r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"test.msg\"; filename=\"test.msg\" \r\n", key, files[key]));
            requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Write(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length);

            StreamWriter fsRequestStream = new StreamWriter(requestStream);

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(files[key], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Write file content to stream, byte by byte
                    fsRequestStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead).ToCharArray());
                }

                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my HTTP Request

> ------=8da381041bc684d Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit  Content-ID: rootpart@soapui.org
>
> <soapenv:Envelope
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:ser="http://www.ca.com/UnicenterServicePlus/ServiceDesk">
> soapenv:Header/ soapenv:Body  ser:createAttachment
> 1200629804
> doc_rep:1002
> cr:966091
> BOOM         BOOM
> </ser:createAttachment> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
> ------=8da381041bc684d
>
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=test.msg
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary  Content-ID: <test.msg>
> Content-Disposition: attachment; name="test.msg"; filename="test.msg"

> ??????

Comment: I get a file with a size 0

Answer (score 0):

Does your binding model uses 'HttpPostedFileBase' as data type? also fixing file size to some value will result in corrupt file so use following code to get size of attachment i.e.

```
mymodel.myFileAttachment.InputStream.Length
```

Comment: My code needs to take a .msg file saved in a folder and send it through an HTTP request

Comment: even then you need to have HttpPostedFileBase datatype for your attachment property in order to upload the file on server and then process.